# javascript document.queryCommandState() "superscript" / "subscript" not work on chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, wysiwyg

I used the mindmup/bootstrap-wysiwyg(github), then added "superscript" and "subscript". It was work fine on firefox, but not work on chrome.
I checked the [javascript code](https://github.com/mindmup/bootstrap-wysiwyg/blob/master/bootstrap-wysiwyg.js), in line: 30

```
document.queryCommandState(command)
```

it always return false

PS, the problem same as https://github.com/mindmup/bootstrap-wysiwyg/issues/63

How to fix this problem??

Comment: Per the linked issue, it is a problem in Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many inconsistencies. See https://github.com/guardian/scribe/blob/master/BROWSERINCONSISTENCIES.md for a fairly comprehensive list.

I think `document.queryCommandState(command)` is actually an Internet Explorer thing. Irrespective of its origin, why do browser makers copy features with such poor fidelity? I don't know. Perhaps you should ask them.

As for checking for sub/super in a browser independent way, you'll have to find the parent node and examine the tag.

Comment: I don't understand how this answers the question.

Comment: @Mathletics - It goes some way to addressing the underlying question of how to deal with the whole cross platform thing and I pointed him at resources. It's not a well defined question, but instead of being a jerk and closing the question I tried to help.